# How Do I invoke/call a button click event handler form another handler? (c# )

Tags: c#, event-handling, compact-framework

I must be missing something obvious - I am new to .NET - been developing in C++/MFC for years.

In an event handler for a button click I would like to then re-use another event handler/click.  However, I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

The bit that may be causing trouble is that the handler for the second item I want to "fire" is not on the same form/context.

It seems that I should just be able to call the method...

But I don't seem to be able to do it.

This is in compact framework/Win Mobile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do one of the following:

- Provide access to the handler's containing class instance (i.e. a reference to that object)
- Make the handler a static so any instance can reference it directly
- Put the handler in some other globally available object (static, singleton, etc) so both consumers can use it
- Use a framework that provides event aggregation so you don't have to worry about such things

Answer (score 2):

How about you factor out the common code into a private method? Then you can call that method from both handlers.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better solution would be to refactor your code so that the work done by the original event handler is contained within a function.

Then both the original handler and the new handler both call the same function.

Comment: This may be conditional, though. It may not be true that he always wants to raise event 2 once event 1 is raised.

Comment: The two don't have to be called together - one, both or none can have access to call the function under whatever conditions are appropriate. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Inside of event handler 1, just raise the event that event handler 2 is "listening" for. So inside event handler 1, put `OnEvent()`. Note that event handler 2 must have already been hooked up to listen to the event.

I can speak in more specificity if you show some more code, but this may be enough.

Answer (score 0):

My ignorance.  I just didn't have visibility to the other handler.  This is a simple problem to solve - I just made the handler visible to the object/form that handles the second event and it is easy to fire the other event.