# C++builder re-use event handler in different form

Tags: event-handling, c++builder, vcl

I have an event handler as a member function of a form. I want to re-use this handler for an event from another form, contained in its own unit. However, I cannot assign the handler using the object inspector.

In [1], the problem seems to be solved enabling 'visibility' of the handler to the 2nd form, although I do not know how that applies to c++(builder).

I reckon that it would be smarter not to define the handler as a member function. What would be the best approach for this?

Thanks and best regards

[1] [How Do I invoke/call a button click event handler form another handler? (c# )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433428/how-do-i-invoke-call-a-button-click-event-handler-form-another-handler-c)

Answer (score 1):

You can also assign event handlers in code itself without using the object inspector. For example

```
   TButton* pButton = new TButton(NULL);
   pButton->OnClick = MyCustomButtonClickHandlerFunction;
```

of course your custom event handler function prototype must be the same as that of the event handler in question. I use this kind of thing all the time, as when you are creating forms dynamically you are unable to use the object inspector anyway.

In your case, assigning an event handler from another class may be inappropriate although it would depend on the class and how the function accesses internal members. If you could redesign the handler to not be a member function, I cannot see why you couldn't use it for both classes. I have used member functions of other classes as event handlers for forms and buttons and other GUI objects, although the VCL objects are usually dynamically created as member variables of that class.

Comment: I tried to implement the handler as a non-member function in a different header (funk.c) and assign it to teh event of my chart on creation of my form

    chrtRight->OnGetAxisLabel = chrtGetAxisLabel;

Unfortunately, I get E2034, conversion from Type1 to Type2 not possible. If I use the same function as a member, it seems to work. I wonder why conversion (void -> TAxisOnGetLabel) is attempted.